# Excel file saved as htm to render properly when uploaded in SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-services, excel-online

I use DriveToWeb to host a webpage (and supporting files) with OneDrive. My website is basically an Excel file saved to .htm file so it has supporting files.

Why do I save Excel files to .htm files within Excel Desktop? For me to just save time, they are converted to web pages in an instant.

My problem is how to replicate the same on SharePoint (basically in just a library folder). I tried it but when I try to view the main .htm page it prompts me to open Excel Online.

Is there any other ways to trick SharePoint?

My sample is the link below:

[Click here](https://zz2tjbwgzir2mu5bjw39cw-on.drv.tw/excel_file/excel_file.htm)
Any suggestion?

I tried iFrame, I tried renaming it to .aspx...

My limitations:

- No access to SharePoint Designer
- No access to SharePoint Design Manager

I am open to:

- Redirects
- Embedding it some other way (not with iFrame)
- Others

I have not learned about Excel Services yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I just want my site within SharePoint static.. I am not sure if Excel Services can help me about my problem..

Comment: I have a SharePoint Designer now, our IT just installed it.